# How to create extra PT_NULL program headers in a binary using linker script

Tags: linker, gnu

I need to create a few extra PT_NULL program headers while linking the binary, so that I can add new segments in the binary later. 
I started with this linker script, and it does not seem to affect the binary, i.e.
it does not create those extra null program headers.

```
PHDRS
{
   PT_PHDR ;
   PT_INTERP ;
   PT_LOAD ;
   PT_LOAD ;
   PT_DYNAMIC ;
   PT_NULL ;
   PT_NULL ;
   PT_NULL ;
} ;
```

Any help appreciated. 
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with help of the [lief](https://lief.quarkslab.com/) library:

```
from lief.ELF import Segment, SEGMENT_TYPES

binary = lief.parse("bin_elf")
null = Segment()
null.type=SEGMENT_TYPES.NULL
null.alignment = 0x1000
binary.add(null)
binary.write("bin_elf.modified")
```